# Yii Controller cannot find the requested view

Tags: php, yii

I am encountering this error when rendering "error" view

```
ApiController cannot find the requested view "error".
```

All directories are in small letters. I am running Yii on Linux Machine

```
Sample Code:

class ApiController extends Api
{
    private $api;
    private $placesapikey;

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct("Api");
    $uri = explode('=', Yii::app()->request->getQueryString());
    $this->api = end($uri);
    $this->placesapikey = "";

    if ($this->api != Yii::app()->params['apikey'] || $this->api == '')
    {
        $error['data']['title'] = "Un-Authorized Access";
        $error['data']['message'] = "You are not authorized to access or view this area";
        $this->render('error', $error);
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: write the sample code ..

Comment: Well, does the view file exist or not? Also, why are you writing a constructor? That's what [`init`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#init-detail) is for!

Comment: you'll also need to add where in the directory structure is the _error.php_ view and where is the controller?

Comment: @Jon Thats out of the question why I am writing the Constructor ;) and the same code is working on my local Server (Mac OSX Lion) but when I push the same code to my AWS EC2 (Linux) instance it throws above error. And of course view file exists

Comment: @bool.dev View: protected/views/api/error.php Controller: protected/controllers/ApiController.php

Comment: have you tried the complete path? as in `'/api/error'`

Comment: @bool.dev nope didn't tried it but now when I tried its working Thanks. But still curious to know the reason when the same code is working on Local machine why not on Linux machine ? and also can you post your answer so that I can accept that.

Comment: This is rather hacky, but you could modify [`CController::resolveViewFile`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#resolveViewFile-detail) to replace the last `return false` with a `throw new CException($viewFile . '.php')` to see what file it's actually looking for. The most common reason for things like this to fail in Linux is filename case sensitivity - are you using `api` or `Api` in the URL?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try:

```
$this->render('/api/error', $error);
```

Comment: I'm not really sure why this is happening!! but could be due to some htaccess rules, just guessing, i'm also deploying my stuff on amazon, and local dev on mac, so if and when i face such an issue i'll get back to you for sure.

Comment: can your controller find the other views, btw? for example in the action methods?

Comment: I used the htaccess code from the official Yii guide http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#hiding-x-23x

Comment: Yes it can find all the actionMethods everything is working fine except the views within ApiController and you know what the strange thing is I have another Controller MainController.php and from that I am calling a view "index.php" within /protected/views/main/index.php like $this->render('index'); and its working fine :D

Comment: ok, this is interesting, hopefully we can crack this, i'll let you know if i find something

Comment: Sure, if I'll find something I'll post it here

Comment: i think either [`getViewPath()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#getViewPath-detail) or [`Yii::app()->findLocalizedFile()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#findLocalizedFile-detail) is failing, to check it place calls to both and see the outputs, in your constructor check the value of `$this->getViewPath()` and `Yii::app()->findLocalizedFile('error.php')` and let me know what they are.

Comment: i think getViewPath is failing, because `'/api/error'` works and `'error'` doesn't